# ODB: create a db success but db file no exist

Tags: database, sqlite, c++11, odb

I try to new a ODB dataBase, however, sometimes, `xxx.db` is not exist even I `new` db success.
 With the code under, it can't catch exception however,it can enter `if(!_file)`

```
string dbFile = getPalBundle()->getFileStorageProvider()->getDocumentsPath(userId + "/xxx.db");

  auto db = std::shared_ptr<odb::sqlite::database>(new odb::sqlite::database(dbFile, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, false));


    if(db == nullptr)
    {
        ret = false;
    }

    // check database avalible
    try {
        db->schema_version();
    } catch (...) {
        DLOG(kTagDaoFactory, "Datase file damaged, logout");
        ret = false;
    }

    fstream _file;
    _file.open(dbFile, ios::in);
    if (!_file) {
        ret = false;
        DLOG(kTagDaoFactory, "Data base file no exist, logout");
    }
```

I have no idea what happens, could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) for `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` says:

> The database is … created if it does not already exist.

The database file is written only when actually needed (to allow to set parameters such as the page size for the new database), so it's possible that for a completely empty database, there is no file.

Comment: Do you mean that it's possible that we create an empty database in memory which is not exist as a file until something has been written into it?

Comment: That's what I wrote.